How to set environmental variables for Vector.dev?
I have read the documentation page and can't figure out how to set environment variables. I know in the configuration file, I need to use something like ${SOURCE_TOKEN}  or $SOURCE_TOKEN. But where do I set it?
I have tried the following:
export SOURCE_TOKEN=value

I have also put the export SOURCE_TOKEN=value name in the .bashrc file and reload the file with source .bashrc. Nothing seems to work.
I get this when I run Vector:
2024-04-10T08:42:16.548863Z  INFO vector::app: Log level is enabled. level="info"
2024-04-10T08:42:16.549869Z  INFO vector::app: Loading configs. paths=["/etc/vector/vector.yaml"]
2024-04-10T08:42:16.550374Z ERROR vector::cli: Configuration error. error=Missing environment variable in config. name = "SOURCE_TOKEN"
2024-04-10T08:42:16.550390Z ERROR vector::cli: Configuration error. error=Missing environment variable in config. name = "SOURCE_TOKEN"
2024-04-10T08:42:16.550399Z ERROR vector::cli: Configuration error. error=Missing environment variable in config. name = "SOURCE_TOKEN"
2024-04-10T08:42:16.550408Z ERROR vector::cli: Configuration error. error=Missing environment variable in config. name = "SOURCE_TOKEN"
2024-04-10T08:42:16.550412Z ERROR vector::cli: Configuration error. error=Missing environment variable in config. name = "SOURCE_TOKEN"
2024-04-10T08:42:16.550420Z ERROR vector::cli: Configuration error. error=Missing environment variable in config. name = "SOURCE_TOKEN"
2024-04-10T08:42:16.550426Z ERROR vector::cli: Configuration error. error=Missing environment variable in config. name = "SOURCE_TOKEN"
2024-04-10T08:42:16.550433Z ERROR vector::cli: Configuration error. error=Missing environment variable in config. name = "SOURCE_TOKEN"


You're probably just missing something. Everything should work fine. Here is an example:
$ vector --version                                                                                                            
vector 0.37.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu c1da408 2024-03-26 13:41:34.870460047)

# config
$ cat /tmp/vector.yaml                                                                                                        
sources:
  generate_syslog:
    type:   "demo_logs"
    format: "syslog"
    count:  100

transforms:
  remap_syslog:
    inputs:
      - "generate_syslog"
    type:   "remap"
    source: |
            structured = parse_syslog!(.message)
            . = merge(., structured)            

sinks:
  emit_syslog:
    inputs:
      - "remap_syslog"
    type: "console"
    encoding:
      codec: ${SOURCE_TOKEN}


# run without SOURCE_TOKEN
vector -c vector.yaml
# ...                                                                                                      
# 2024-04-16T20:19:56.180478Z ERROR vector::cli: Configuration error. error=Missing environment variable in config. name = "SOURCE_TOKEN"

# let's try with text
export SOURCE_TOKEN=text
vector -c vector.yaml

# ...                                                                                                   
# We're gonna need a bigger boat
# There's a breach in the warp core, captain
# ...

# let's try with json
export SOURCE_TOKEN=json
vector -c vector.yaml

# ...
# {"appname":"b0rnc0nfused","facility":"daemon","hostname":"for.kosher","message":"Great Scott! We're never gonna reach 88 mph with the flux capacitor in its current state!","msgid":"ID619","procid":3582,"service":"vector","severity":"alert","source_type":"demo_logs","timestamp":"2024-04-16T20:24:48.993Z","version":2}
# {"appname":"KarimMove","facility":"uucp","hostname":"for.chrome","message":"A bug was encountered but not in Vector, which doesn't have bugs","msgid":"ID31","procid":1211,"service":"vector","severity":"alert","source_type":"demo_logs","timestamp":"2024-04-16T20:24:49.993Z","version":2}
# ...

Docker container example(JFYI: you can use --env-file argument):
docker run -e SOURCE_TOKEN=json -v /tmp/vector.yaml:/etc/vector/vector.yaml timberio/vector:0.37.1-alpine

